# How to use aggregate to group by half hour with rounding?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using `$group` to group my post by hour like:

```
"$group" : {
    "_id" : {
        "$hour" : {
            $add : ["$createdAt", 10*60*60*1000]
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

But now I also want to group by half-of-hour, it's mean:

```
2:30 => 3:00
2:29 => 2:00
```

How I using mongo aggregate to pass this trouble?
Sr for my bad English. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather the +10 here is for a timezone adjustment. The same basic principles apply to producing the date with 30 minute rounding, except you want to first just convert to a numeric value and work back the intervals via a modulo ( [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) ):

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [
                        { "$add": [ "$createdAt", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10 ] },
                        new Date(0) 
                    ]},
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [
                            { "$add": [ "$createdAt", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10 ] }, 
                            new Date(0)
                        ]},
                        1000 * 60 * 30
                    ]}
                ]},
                new Date(0)
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 } // or whatever accumulation required
    }}
```

Using the epoch date ( `Date(0)` ) with a [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/subtract) operation from the stored date ( adjusted ) will return the milliseconds since epoch as a numeric value from the date stored. The modulo operation to the milliseconds in 30 minutes returns the remainder from the current date and you then `$subtract` that again to get a rounded interval.

The same is present with the [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/add) operation where the epoch date object to a numeric value returns a `Date` again.

So every interval start is now the grouping key, as of every 30 minutes.

You can alternately use date aggregation operators, but this returns a BSON `Date` object which will be translated in API rather than just an numeric value for the "minutes" interval.

It's just standard "date math", so all the same operations apply.